# LabelBinazer questions?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I tried to calculate sensitivity score for my simple classification problem

```
 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, recall_score
 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
 from sklearn import preprocessing

 X = df.drop(columns='output_feature')
 y = df.output_feature

 lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
 y = lb.fit_transform(y).ravel()

 knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
 knn.fit(X,y)

 y_pred_knn = knn.predict(df_prediction_input)
 recall_score(lb.fit_transform(df_actual.output_feature), y_pred_knn)
```

I got the result of 0.575. My actual output feature is 'churn' and 'not churn' corresponding with the value of 0 and 1. How do I know that what is the target class? I want my target class is 'churn', so the value should be 0 or 1 and how I can I change that?

Comment: Please explain with an example what you want

Answer (score 0):

First, to check which label is encoded by what number, put the following somewhere appropriate (e.g. just above `knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)`
line)

```
print(lb.classes_)
```

The first output will be matched to a 0, the second will be to 1. For example if you get

```
array(['churn', 'not churn'], dtype='<U7')
```

it means, **"churn": 0**, and **not churn: 1**

If this is the case, you sould modify your last line as:

```
recall_score(lb.fit_transform(df_actual.output_feature), y_pred_knn, pos_label=0)
```

basically you are saying that positive label is **churn** (since churn is encoded as 0).

However, if "churn" is encoded as 1, you do not have to change the last line.